# Combine jQuery scroll and load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to detect if the page is scrolled beyond 150px.

The code works fine but I'd like to know if theres any way to combine the scroll and load functions as currently I'm repeating code.

Appreciate any help.

```js
var nav = $(".header");
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
   nav.addClass("header-bg");
  } else {
   nav.removeClass("header-bg");
  }
 });
 
 $(window).load(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
   nav.addClass("header-bg");
  } else {
   nav.removeClass("header-bg");
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out, for anyone else who gets stuck with:

```js
var nav = $(".header");
 $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
   nav.addClass("header-bg");
  } else {
   nav.removeClass("header-bg");
  }
 });
```